# Interminable loading page on click on load button

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have a React application. On one of pages I write any functions but i cant tast this functions because when i wanna load page (for cleaning page for example (Ctrl + Shift + R)) the page will interminable update. This start after that I write some functions with using Firebase Realtime database. I try "debug" it (I commented some piece of code) but the page continue interminable updete.

App.jsx code:

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Page/LoadingApp';
import Login from './Page/Login';
import SignOrReg from './Page/SignOrReg';
import SuccessAuth from './Page/SuccessAuth';
import SignUp from './Page/SignUp';
import { useState } from 'react';
import UserWay from './Page/UserWay';
import DriverWay from './Page/DriverWay';

function App() {
  const [role, setRole] = useState('');
  const handleRole = (role) => {
    setRole(role);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/auth" element={<SignOrReg />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/sign-up" element={<SignUp />} />
        <Route path="/success-auth" element={<SuccessAuth role={role} />} />
        <Route path="/user-way" element={<UserWay />} />
        <Route path="/driver-way" element={<DriverWay />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Driver.jsx code (interminable updated page component):

```
import Button from '../components/UI-UX/Button';
import MapWithRoute from '../components/MapWithRoute';
import styles from '../module-style/driver-way.module.css';
import OrderList from '../components/UI-UX/OrderList';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue } from 'firebase/database';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../firebase';

const DriverWay = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const db = getDatabase();

  const [uid, setUid] = useState('');

  const listen = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      setUid(user.email.split('@')[0]);
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className={styles.driver__way__block}>
      <MapWithRoute />
      <OrderList driverUid={uid} visible={visible} />
      <div className={styles.button}>
        <Button
          type="submit"
          onClick={() => setVisible(true)}
          width={19.9375}
          height={3.6875}
          bgc="FFE500"
          btnText="Показать заказы"
          btnTextColor="FFF"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DriverWay;
```

The last one component is OrderList.jsx (this component get datas with Realtimes database and handle order window):

```
import styles from '../../module-style/ui-ux-styles/order-list.module.css';
import { update, ref, getDatabase, onValue } from 'firebase/database';
import Button from './Button';
import { useState } from 'react';

const OrderList = (props) => {
  const orderlist = ['content'];

  const [nowGeo, setNowGeo] = useState();
  const [endGeo, setEndGeo] = useState();
  const [orderInfo, setOrderInfo] = useState([]);

  const db = getDatabase();
  const dbRef = ref(db, 'orders/');

  onValue(
    dbRef,
    (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        setNowGeo(childSnapshot.val().nowGeolocation);
        setEndGeo(childSnapshot.val().endGeolocation);
      });
    },
    {
      onlyOnce: true,
    }
  );

  const handleClick = () => {
    const updates = {};
    updates['users/drivers/' + props.driverUid + '/takeOrderData'] = Date.now();
    updates['user/drivers/' + props.driverUid + '/userNowGeo'] = nowGeo;
    update(ref(db), updates);

    setOrderInfo([nowGeo, endGeo]);
    console.log(orderInfo);
  };

  if (props.visible == true) {
    if (orderlist.length === 0) {
      return (
        <div className={styles.order__list__block}>
          <div>
            <img src="/img/no-order-icon.jpg" alt="" />
            <h3>Упс! Ничего не найденно</h3>
            <p>
              На данный момент заказов нет. Подождите ещё чуть чуть и посторите
              действие снова
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className={styles.order__list__block}>
          <div className={styles.order__list}>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              onClick={() => handleClick}
              width={19.9375}
              height={3.6875}
              bgc="FFE500"
              btnText="Принять заказ"
              btnTextColor="FFF"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  } else {
    console.log('error');
  }
};

export default OrderList;
```

Thanks for helping!!